# Connect to Server via SSL with various Cipher strengths and algorithms in C#

Tags: c#, ssl, encryption, sslstream

Searched around a bit, found different tools to check weak ciphers.  How can I determine what ciphers/alogrithms the Server supports via .net/c#?

I can test sslv2, sslv3 and tls via (ssl.protocols.ssl2/ssl3/tls):

```
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
            client.Connect("host", 443);
            using (SslStream Ssl = new SslStream(client.GetStream()))
            {
                Ssl.AuthenticateAsClient("host", null, System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Ssl3, false);
                Console.WriteLine(Ssl.CipherAlgorithm);
                Console.WriteLine(Ssl.CipherStrength);
                Console.WriteLine(Ssl.SslProtocol);
            }
            client.Close();
```

How do I check the algorithms and other weak ciphers via C#? I am looking at SSLDiagnos but it is in c?

Any ideas?

Comment: This link answers the question but was deleted as an answer: http://www.bolet.org/TestSSLServer/ (C# source for TestSSLServer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[CipherAlgorithm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream.cipheralgorithm.aspx) and HashAlgorithm properties of SslStream. You define what is "weak" for you, and check the negotiated algorithm against your list of "weak" ones.

Update: Sorry for misunderstanding the question. The server doesn't seem to send the list of supported ciphersuites, so the only option is to enable one cipher suite at a time on the client and attempt to connect using it. I don't see that SslStream allows you to specify allowed ciphersuite(s), however you can use our [SecureBlackbox](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/net-ssl.php) components for this - they let you fine-tune the component (SSL client) easily.

Comment: I am trying to determine what ciphers/algorithms the server supports. Similar to what http://superuser.com/questions/109213/is-there-a-tool-that-can-test-what-ssl-tls-cipher-suites-a-particular-website-off

Answer (score 1):

The server chooses a ciphersuite to use from the list requested by the client. I.e. you should take some library that allows to enable/disable certain ciphersuites, and try to connect to the server enabling suites one-by-one. SslStream doesn't support flexible ciphersuites adjustment.

Answer (score 0):

I would still take a look at ssldiagnos and maybe port it to c# using OpenSSL.NET? http://sourceforge.net/projects/openssl-net/
Then all you would have to do is to port the c-code into c# and leave the OpenSSL-code.

Answer (score 0):

The ssldiagnos application is now merged with another tool: sslpressure which does not use openssl at all, just check the initial client hello (much simpler), maybe you can use that as a template for your project.